# Synchronize data QField=>QGIS

Tags: qfield

I recorded data outside which I now want to import into my QGIS project. In QField I see the recorded data. Via "open local file" => "imported projects" => "Export to folder" I saved the data on the device. Then I connected the mobile phone (Android) to the computer and copied the folder to the import directory. I openend the QGIS project, clicked on "import” and selected the folder. Data is loaded, but the edited layers are not found and no data is imported.
I switched of the phone many time, I tried to save the data in a different folder, but no success.

Comment: Now I have created a link using the "Send compressed folder to..." option and can send the data as a ZIP via email to the PC. This data could be read into QGIS. Is there an error in the program? Or may I need any updates? QField Version 2.6.3 - Geeky Gecko, QGIS 3.22.11

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to transfer the collected data from QField to QGIS.

Comment: Was your QField Project specifically set-up as an offline project. If not, you cannot 'synchronise', it is just a stand-alone project.

Comment: I worked on the project in QGIS, then I transferred it via QField Sync to my phone, I took data outside and tried to trasfer the data back. It used to work that way before.